# Dynamically insert angular directive into HTML

Tags: angularjs

I have a number of directives in my angular module, these are named: MyDirective1, MyDirective2, ... , MyDirectiveN

I maintain a list of directive names as well: MyDirectiveList: ['MyDirective1', 'MyDirective2', ... , 'MyDirectiveN']

In HTML, I would like to display one of the directives based a variable (selectedDirective) which holds the directive name (either with ng-if or ng-show).

```
<div ng-repeat="directiveName in MyDirectiveList">

   <div ng-if="selectedDirective == directiveName">

   ...directive shall go in here...

   </div>

</div>
```

I could insert into the element using $injector and $compile in the controller but I wonder if there is more angular way of doing this directly in the html with angular directives.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are manipulating the DOM, you should do that with a directive.

Well, you may reply that ng-repeat and ng-if are directives as well, and you are right. But you are just currently calling an army because someone stole your wallet.

The best solution seems to be the one presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29403342/6199193), ie a directive to rule them all.

This solution is better for two reasons :

1) You are no longer theorically able to create and not display one thousand DOM object just for displaying one.

2) You can pass a custom json of data if your directives needs to (note that you can only pass it through a unique json and not adapt to the needs of you directives, ie multiple fields with smart two way data-biding).